# Xamarin: change Navigation properties between pages

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, navigation

I had customized a navigation page in order to have a Image through navigation bar, based on setting

```
IsNavigationBarTranslucent="True"
```

It works but then, when I navigate from this page pushing a new page by

```
await Navigation.PushAsync(new MyChildPage());
```

the navigation follow `translucent`. I try to change this properties without success. Bacically I want traslucent on the first page on navigation (I got it) and a "defult" navigation bar on seconds pages.

EDIT:
I think I had to use `DisableTranslucentNavigationBar` but I can`t understand how.

My code for custom  NavigatioRenderer is:

```
public class CustomNavigationRenderer : NavigationRenderer
    {
        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();
            NavigationBar.SetBackgroundImage(new UIImage(), UIBarMetrics.Default); 
            NavigationBar.ShadowImage = new UIImage();                               
        }
```

that works as I want when use:

```
NavigationPage _myNav = new CustomNavigation(MyFirsNavPage);
```

NAvigation is transparent and the image I put on MyFirsNavPage xaml page appear as background of navigation.

But when I go to another page on stack, the navigation still translucent.

I use

```
(this.Parent as Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPage).On<iOS>().DisableTranslucentNavigationBar();
```

just before push to SecondPage: the navigation appears now but with white background (not with the general NavigationPage BarBackgroundColor setted on styl )

Any help?

Comment: In other pages `constructor` you can again change the behavior of `NavigationBar`.

Comment: Have you an example? I tried it but navigation still translucent.

Comment: Provide some code where are changing Navigation bar edit your question. So that It would be easy to guess me.

Comment: I just edit my question.